# Elementary solution: Show that for $n\ge 2,$ the quantity $[P_{n+5}-P_{n+4}-P_{n+3}+P_n]$ does not depend on $n,$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations, contest-math, combinations

Let $P_n$ be the number of permutations $\pi$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that $[|i-j|=1\text{ implies }|\pi(i)-\pi(j)|\le 2]$for all $i,j$ in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}.$ Show that for $n\ge 2,$ the quantity $[P_{n+5}-P_{n+4}-P_{n+3}+P_n]$ does not depend on $n,$ and find its value

This is putnam 2015 B4.

Anyone has any elementary solution for this problem, I am a class 8 guy. The handout says to use Recursion and Induction, but I am not able to think of any.

Please help!

Comment: Have you read Kiran's solution?

Comment: I tried to, but couldn't understand that nicely

Comment: What is Kiran's solution?

Comment: @Phicar Kiran KiKedlaya compiles Putnam solutions (which are considered "official" but are not released from an official source). E.g [2015 B5](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2015s.pdf).

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks!

Comment: @Raheel I encourage you to read that solution, work through it, and then list out what you're confused by or do not understand. There are several ways to set up the recurrence, like the note at the end states.